# Quick algorithm for distance between 2 points on a grid?

Tags: java, distance, solver

Given a grid of width by length (say 5 x 4) and an array of X and Y coords for points on that grid, print the distance from each point on the grid to the coords as below:

width = 5

len = 4

x coords = (2,4)

y coords = (2,3)

```
2123
1012
2112
2101
3212
```

A move "across" is + 2, vertical or horizontal move is +1

Assume xCoords.length = yCoords.length

I will post my solution later, or rather an attempt at a solution. I got stuck trying to come up with a function to transpose distance from grid coordinates (i,j) to coordinates for the points... So basically

```
for i .. width
  for j .. length
    getDistance(i,j, xCoords,yCoords)
```

(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3)

(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) (1,3)

(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) (2,3)

etc...

To the actual distance values at those coordinates.

Comment: Are you looking for [the Pythagorean Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)?

Comment: No, I mean, I know what it is, I'm just not sure how it fits in here? How do i figure out the distance from (i,j) to the coordinate at xCoords/yCoords? I don't know how to make that step

Comment: The shortest way from the bottom left corner to the upper corner is the hypotenuse. If you have the coordinates for the two corners you can calculate the hypotenuse and thereby also the shortest route (distance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the distance to the nearest `coord` among the ones given in the vector, i.e.

```
for i 0 .. width
    for j 0 .. length
        best = distance(i, j, coords[0].x, coords[0].y)
        for k 1 .. coordVector // Skip first element
            best = min(best, distance(i, j, coords[k].x, coords[k].y)
        result[i][j] = best
```

The third nested loop checks the distance from the given coordinate to all coordinates in the vector of (x<sub>*i*</sub>, y<sub>*i*</sub>), picks the shortest one, and stores it in the variable `best`. Note that `best` is initialized with the distance to the first point in the vector, so the nested loop starts with the second point.

All you need now is a calculator for `distance`. According to the problem description, you are looking for [*Manhattan Distance*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) because a diagonal step is weighted as 2, meaning it's the same as one step horizontally plus one step vertically:

```
distance(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    horizontal = abs(x1-x0)
    vertical = abs(y0-y1)
    return horizontal + vertical
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: One thing to note, every time you call distance for a zero indexed grid you need to do+1 for i,j so actually function call will look like so: distance(i+1, j+1, coords[0].x, coords[0].y)

Comment: @Nik That's right, coordinate translation is definitely a concern one needs to address when converting this pseudocode to a program in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getDistance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    return Math.abs(x1 - x2) + Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}
```

Comment: `Math.pow((x1 - x2)*2, 2)` why are you multiplying by 2?

Comment: @Gendarme The question said "accross" was actually units of 2.

Comment: @Gendarme Wait, maybe the OP meant "accross" as diagonal? I'm going to edit, because I think I misunderstood.

Comment: So `sqrt(2) == 2`?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Pythagorean theorem. `sqrt((i-xCords)*(i-xCords)+(j-yCords)*(j-yCords))`

Answer (score 0):

Related: [I want to calculate the distance between two points in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431032/i-want-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-points-in-java)

distance = Math.sqrt( Math.pow((i-xCords), 2) + Math.pow((j-yCords), 2));